# SQL join with multiple values in one column separated by comma

Tags: mysql

I need to join two tables, but one of my table column has multiple values and each of them is separated by comma. while other table has values for that id's. See the example below

Table 1
ID | Value
---------------
1  | 34,54
2  | 76
3  | 12,8
4  | 3,90,78

Table 2
ID | Value
---------------
34 | Green
54 | Red
76 | Black
12 | White
8  | Blue
3  | Orange
.
.
.

I want output to look like

Output Table
table1.ID | table2.Value
---------------
1 | Green,Red
2 | Black
3 | White,Blue

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: I see serious need of normalization.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty thanks for the concern, anyways i am in a soup prepared by some cook. Any quick fix for it?

Comment: Posted an answer this should do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you do normalization here is a way which is not so efficient by using `find_in_set` and `group_concat`

```
select 
t1.id,
group_concat(t2.value) as value 
from table1 t1 
join table2 t2 on find_in_set(t2.id,t1.value) 
group by t1.id
```

Comment: How can I perform the same query in Oracle ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT service_type.id 
GROUP_CONCAT( usermeta.meta_value ) AS value 
FROM wpxx_service_type AS service_type 
JOIN wpxx_usermeta AS usermeta ON FIND_IN_SET( service_type.id, usermeta.meta_value ) 
WHERE usermeta.meta_key = 'work_area' 
GROUP BY service_type.id Order By service_type.service_title ASC
```

Where I have Join two Table wpxx_service_type AND wpxx_usermeta usermeta. It works for me. :)